# switch user and run a command with sudo, from wtihin a bash script

Tags: bash, sudo, su

I have a command I need to run with sudo, but first I need the script to su to an admin account and ask for the pw.

Currently, I can only get this to work if I call a second script as the new user, like this:

**launch.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# how can we just put the script here instead of a separate file?
su -c "sudo -S ./.launchStage2.sh" -m admin_user
```

**.launchStage2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
source /root/pyusb/bin/activate
cd /root/pyusb
python stormLauncher.py
deactivate
cd ~
```

Is there a way to remove the second script and run it from within the first script?  Bonus :) currently it asks for the password twice, once for su and once for the sudo, is there a way to only have it ask once?

Edit: I don't want my regular user account to be in `sudo`, and instead want to use a seperate admin account that is used when required.  Main reason for this is I'm a teacher in a classroom lab and if students somehow get access to my regular account, they still won't have sudo.  Not sure if that's justified or not, but it's what was recommend to me by my org's IT dept, and isn't part of this question.

Comment: Why `sudo -S`...?

Comment: without the -S I get: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Answer (score 2):

The script can call itself:

```
if ! [ admin_user = "$USER" ] && ! [ root = "$USER" ]; then
    su -c "$0" -m admin_user
elif ! [ root = "$USER" ]; then
    sudo "$0"
else
    source /root/pyusb/bin/activate
    # [...]
fi
```

Comment: this appears to put me into an infinite loop of asking me for my password.  If I `echo "$USER"`, it doesn't change to `admin_user` on the recursive calls

Comment: @43Tesseracts Doesn't make sense to me. Works here.